# A word for a poem that portrays pictures in your mind?

Tags: word-request

There is this poem that describes an event and it is so good when I read it all the event details shape in my mind. I need an adjective to describe that poem.

Is *depictive* used for such cases? What about *descriptive*? Or other better suggestions?

Comment: In the early part of the last century, the [Imagist](https://www.poets.org/poetsorg/text/brief-guide-imagism) school of poetry attempted to do exactly this. However, the term *imagist poem* might be confusing, as it's not clear whether it's a poem written by somebody who called themself an *Imagist*, or a poem that creates an image in the reader's mind.

Answer (score 1):

One could say that such a poem is "vividly descriptive" or that it "paints a vivid image" perhaps. To say simply "descriptive" suggests that it focuses on description, but does not say how good it is. "Imagist" I think suggests a poem from that school, specifically. One could say that the poem brings a scene strongly to life.